# Python request to curl request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

Sample python code which send sample message.

```
import requests

url = "dns.com/end"
msg = "test connection"
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Basic asdfasdf"}

requests.post(url, json=msg, headers=headers)
```

Now, I'd like to send exactly the same message using curl request.

```
curl -X POST --data "test connection" -H '"Content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Basic asdfasdf"' dns.com/end
```

I'm getting an error:
"status":404,"message":"No message available"

Comment: What result do you get when you use the Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

- You are not sending JSON data, you forgot to encode your data to JSON. Encoding the string value `test connection` to JSON becomes `"test connection"`, but *quotes have meaning in your shell too*, so you need to add *extra* quoting or escapes.
- You can't set multiple headers with a single `-H` entry. Use multiple, one per header set. Headers don't need quotes, only the shell needs quoting to prevent argument splitting on spaces.

This would be equivalent:

```sh
curl -X POST \
  --data '"test connection"' \
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic asdfasdf' \
  dns.com/end
```

Demo using https://httpbin.org:

```sh
$ curl -X POST \
>   --data '"test connection"' \
>   -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
>   -H 'Authorization: Basic asdfasdf' \
>   https://httpbin.org/post

{
  "args": {},
  "data": "\"test connection\"",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Authorization": "Basic asdfasdf",
    "Content-Length": "17",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5e5c399c-201cc8007165873084d4cf38"
  },
  "json": "test connection",
  "origin": "<ip address>",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

which matches the Python equivalent:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
>>> msg = "test connection"
>>> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json",
...             "Authorization": "Basic asdfasdf"}
>>> response = requests.post(url, json=msg, headers=headers)
>>> print(response.text)
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "\"test connection\"",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization": "Basic asdfasdf",
    "Content-Length": "17",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.22.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5e5c3a25-50c9db19a78512606a42b6ec"
  },
  "json": "test connection",
  "origin": "<ip address>",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```